# Error compiling jsx with broserify for reactJS

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs, jsx

I'm newer on ReactJS's world. I'm trying to do a testing app and I obtain the next:
I have the next Component:

**BtnLink.js**

```
var BtnLink = new React.createClass({

    getInitialState:function(){
        return {
            class : 'btn btn-primary',
            label :  'Continuar'
        }
    },
    changeButton : function(){

    },
    render : function(){
        return(
            <div>hola</div>
        );
    }
});
```

This code is on BtnLink.jsx file, and is included in my index.js file, as in broserify documentation.

**index.js**

```
var Boton   = require('./components/BtnLink.jsx');

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("here with me");
        ReactDOM.render(<BtnLink>, document.getElementbyId('app'))
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

};
```

app.initialize();

But wen I try to run the next wroserify command for create de "js" file:

```
browserify js/src/index.js -o js/dist/index.js
```

The console show error on "hola" line (or " if i change it=. from BtnLink.jsx file. If I change the line for only text, for example "hola" without html selectors the command run ok, but this is not the idea because the React's components may return html without troubles. right? Can anyone know what is the error?

UPDATED 6.1.2017 
I also tried with babel, using the next command

```
$ babel --presets es2017 js/src/components --watch --out-dir js/dist/components
```

and the response is the same as browserify

```
js\src\components\BtnLink.jsx -> js\dist\components\BtnLink.js
SyntaxError: js/src/components/BtnLink.jsx: Unexpected token (6:3)
  4 |   render : function(){
  5 |           return(
> 6 |                   <div>hola</div>
    |                   ^
  7 |           )
  8 |   }
  9 | });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comment. Inside jsx file, comments shouldo go like this:

```
{/* Comment */}
```

Comment: Hi, the comment //<a href="#">text</a> I only add in this post for show the real "component" but i tried without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
babel --presets es2017
```

will convert `ES2017` features, and nothing else. If you're looking to use JSX, you'd want to use `babel-preset-react` and chances are you'll want to use `babel-preset-env` or `babel-preset-latest` alongside `react`.